# not able to change background image using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i got a css file whose path is resources/style/test.css and an image folder whose path is resources/images/characters. on using the following class and html

```
    .character
{
position:relative;
margin-top:-4.8%;
margin-left:85%;
height:51px;
width:51px;
background-color:#e3f4fd;
background-image:url(../images/characters/9.png);
background-position:center;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

html:

```
 <div class="character" style="display:inline-block;">
</div>
```

it shows me the required image but i want to change this background image using jquery and i write the following url under my conditions

$('.character', this).css("background-image", "url(../images/characters/8.png)");

nothing appears on screen ..

so i want to ask what should be the url so that the image that is changed is displayed on screen?

Comment: Whats the content of the this keyword when you are running the statement?  Try removing and see if it works. $('.character').css("background-image", "url(../images/characters/8.png)");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the html file is at the root, try

```
$('.character', this).css("background-image", "url(resources/images/characters/8.png)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the problem is your jQuery selector, try removing the context param:

```
$('.character', this) to $('.character')
```

Comment: Justin Bicknell no its right ...it is used to specify a specific id so only image of specifed element will change:)

Comment: @user2137186 can you see the resource being requested? Chrome has a network tab in the developer tools that you can use for viewing this

Comment: @user2137186 fair enough, I wasn't sure because 'this' could be anything

Answer (score 0):

for this syntax, you need to use camelCase property names:

change

```
$('.character', this).css("background-image", "url(../images/characters/8.png)");
```

to

```
$('.character', this).css("backgroundImage", "url(../images/characters/8.png)");
```

Comment: You actually don't need that, the first syntax works as well.

Comment: so what do you think the problem is timPetricola ? is the url correct?

Comment: hmm, I've always used camel case in this syntax and dashed in the object syntax. Good to know that's not an issue. Thanks @TimPetricola!

Comment: @user2137186 I tried your code without the context and it works (at least the background-image is changed). So yeah maybe it's not the right url. Try to look at your console to see if you have any 404 error.

Comment: @swatkins You're welcome :) Most of the time I prefer to stick to the css notation but camelcase can be really cool if you change a bunch of properties at the same time via an object. `$('.selector').css({ backgroundImage: 'url(...)', marginTop: 10 });`

Comment: @TimPetricola - am I thinking of this wrong, I thought you used the dashed properties with the object notation and camel case with the other.

Comment: @swatkins You can use both (dashed and CamelCase) with both notations. In object notation you just don't need to escape the property name if you use CamelCase. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu82x/embedded/result/) to see different possibilities for the same result.